# Adverb "other (than)"

Tags: grammar, adjectives, adverbs

The entry of **other** in the [Fowler's dictionary of usage](https://books.google.es/books?id=AvmzBgAAQBAJ&lpg=PA584&ots=gKr6KWoxzl&dq=%22other%20was%20formerly%20often%20(and%20still%20occasionally)%20an%20uninflected%20plural%22&hl=es&pg=PA584#v=onepage&q=%22other%20was%20formerly%20often%20(and%20still%20occasionally)%20an%20uninflected%20plural%22&f=false) reads

> *It never  occurred to me ours would be **other** than a marriage in name only.*
>
> Is ***other*** here an *adjective* linked to *marriage* or an *adverb* linked
> to *be* ? (The answer is a bit of both.)

Could somebody elaborate on what *a bit of both* exactly means?

Comment: Please clarify. The title asks about "other than" but then in the body of the question you ask about "a bit of both". Please can you say which phrase you want us to explain?

Comment: @chasly-supportsMonica https://books.google.es/books?id=AvmzBgAAQBAJ&lpg=PA584&ots=gKr6KWoxzl&dq=%22other%20was%20formerly%20often%20(and%20still%20occasionally)%20an%20uninflected%20plural%22&hl=es&pg=PA584#v=onepage&q=%22other%20was%20formerly%20often%20(and%20still%20occasionally)%20an%20uninflected%20plural%22&f=false

Comment: That doesn't help. Do you want us to explain "other than" or do you want us to explain "a bit of both" as mentioned in the final sentence of your question?  Note that the convention on Stack Exchange is to answer only one question at a time. You can submit two questions if necessary.

Comment: 'Other than' is best seen as composite here (and indeed M-W labels it a [compound] preposition in this usage).

Comment: "Other" is an adjective with a _than_ preposition phrase as comparative complement. The whole AdjP "other than a marriage in name only" is predicative complement of "be"

Answer (score 0):

'**Other**' is an adjective, but '**other than**' is an adverb phrase that's modifying the adjective.

So, '**Other than**' being the adverb that it is, acts upon 'to be.'

But '**other**' by itself can't be linked as an adverb 'to be.'

What they mean by *a bit of both* is maybe...

**Other** connects with '*marriage*' as an adjective.

**Other than** connects with '*to be*' an adverb.

Answer (score 0):

> *It never occurred to me ours would be other than a marriage in name*
> *only.*

"Other" is an adjective with the preposition phrase "than a marriage in name only" as its comparative complement. We know it's a complement because it's obligatory.

The whole adjective phrase "other than a marriage in name only" then functions as predicative complement of "be".

Comment: I think you're right. If I'm correct, prepositional phrases can act both as adjectives and adverbs. In this case, it's acting as an adverb, but that still doesn't explain why he's saying the answer is a bit of both.

Comment: Not quite. PPs don't act as adjectives and adverbs (they are parts of speech, not functions) but as complements and modifiers. Here the PP is obligatory and hence it is functioning as a subjective **complement** of "be", where it refers to "ours". Note that obligatory items are always complements. I've no idea what "a bit of both" is supposed to mean, or where it came from. The link provided seems irrelevant.

Comment: 'The parrot on the guava tree' --> Here on the guava tree is a PP that's an adjective. "I'm angry because of her.' --> here, because of her is a PP that's an adjverb.

Comment: That's not how English grammar is analysed. In "The parrot on the guava tree", the PP "on the guava tree" is **preposition phrase** functioning as **modifier** of "parrot". Not everything that modifies a noun is an adjective! In "I'm angry because of her", the PP "because of her" is an **adjunct of reason**. Note that 'adverb' is a part of speech, not a function.

Comment: I should've been more careful with my words before. I intended to say that the parrot modifier was doing the job of an adjective, which is to modify a noun. It's the same with the second example, too. I didn't mean to say that a PP is an adjective or an adverb, lol, but they can act like an adjective or an adverb, don't they? I get that you're saying PPs are modifiers, but they are modifying the same way as adjectives and adverbs, so I don't understand why you're saying they can't act in place of Adjs and Advs. I know we're going a bit off-topic, but can you please clarify?